# Troubles with 'parent' fields in equals/hashCode of concrete class(or case class) which extends a multiply traits(with concrete fields)

Tags: scala, equals, hashcode, traits, case-class

I'm new in Scala and confused about traits mixing. I'm using multiple traits to store some group of fields and mix them with concrete class.

The global question is about how equals and hashCode methods will operate those fields (fields in traits can have default values).

Actually I'm not planning have a bunch of costructors and define all those fields again. My class can have plenty field combinations and I want to use Builder pattern or simple mutators chaining. 
I do not understand how can I operate fields from different traits in my equals and hashCode of concrete class(I only can hardcode logic with them, but can not use 'super.equals()'). Traits can not have its own equals/hashCode methods, or I'm mistaken at some point?

Example:

```
trait Task {  

  var name: Option[String] = None

  var comment: Option[String] = None

  ... // plenty other fields

}

trait Budget {

  var price: Option[Long] = None

}

class Event extends Task with Budget {

  var place: Option[String] = None

  ... // plenty other fields

}
```

When using case classes instead - generated equals/hashCode/toString do not operate parent fields(fields from traits)

Comment: I've spent a week trying to get use of 'mixing' concept in Scala and now I've came to idea that a simple 'Composition' still a great way to achieve my goal

Comment: Composition is almost always preferable to trait stacking. So go with that!

Comment: OK, I though that in Scala this rule was revisited because of traits

Comment: Will see what way will be more compatible with OGM I want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not.
You can easily `override` `equals` and `hashCode` in any trait you like.

```
trait PP {
  override def hashCode(): Int = 1

  override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = true
}

class BB(val z: Int) extends PP {
  override def hashCode(): Int = super.hashCode()

  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = super.equals(obj) && (obj match {
    case b: BB => b.z == z
    case _ => false
  })
}
```

Definetly you should be very careful with hashCode and equals implementation in those traits ( while do type check: `obj.isInstanceOf[otherTrait]` ) to follow contract of those methods.

--

Sample to prove all `equals` are invoked.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  trait T1 {
    override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = {
      println("T1 invoked")
      super.equals(obj)
    }
  }

  trait T2 {
    override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = {
      println("T2 invoked")
      super.equals(obj)
    }
  }
  trait T3 extends T1 {
    override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = {
      println("T3 invoked")
      super.equals(obj)
    }
  }
  class C1 extends T1 with T2 with T3 {
    override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = {
      println("C1 invoked")
      super.equals(obj)
    }
  }

  new C1().equals(new C1())

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

C1 invoked
T3 invoked
T2 invoked
T1 invoked
defined trait T1
defined trait T2
defined trait T3
defined class C1
res7: Boolean = false

scala>

scala>
```

Comment: Make sure you've properly implemented all `equals` methods. They expected to call `super` everywhere.

Comment: Yeah! It is it...I've forgot to call super in all traits.